# I can't seem to find System.Collections.Concurrent on VS2010?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I've got VS2010 and im pretty sure .NET 4.0, as if i try to install it from MS it says do i wish to repair the current version- so i must have it. But i want to create a concurrent dictionary and i cant seem to find the correct packet. I went to references to add it manually but it wasnt in my list?

Comment: works for me. you sure the project is targeting .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you target the .NET 4.0 (or 4.0 Client Profile) Framework. You can do this in the project settings: Right click on your project name in the project explorer, click on settings and keep your eyes open for "Target framework" in the topmost settings-tab.

Comment: Mine is targeting .NET 4.0, but I still don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

- Your project must targeting .NET 4.0 or higher.
- In most of the cases the fastest way to reference the namespace which would be hard to find anyway is to type it yourself at the using directives:

  using System.Collections.Concurrent;

IntelliSense will also help you out while you are typing the namespaces.

If you don't know which namespace should you type after the using keyword, MSDN's web site will help you out; for example if you would like to use ConcurrentDictionary, google for "ConcurrentDictionary MSDN", and navigate to MSDN's site. You will find there the **Namespace** field below the **Inheritance Hierarchy** at the top of the page.

An other way is to use custom tools such as [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Resharper is a really professional and polished tool, but it's not free (after trial).